# <%= does not want to print out in css element

Tags: asp.net, printing

When using link element the asp does not process <%= CssVersion %> but interpret it as literal string

```
 <link href="../../css/style01.css?<%= CssVersion %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

the output of the above is

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style01.css?<%= CssVersion >">
```

But when this is used

```
<script language="javascript" src="../../js/tiutil_1.0.js?<%= CssVersion %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It then print out the correctly as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/tiutil_1.0.js?220409" language="javascript"></script>
```

Any idea why ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this behaviour occur when the `<link>` and `<script>` elements are both in the same place in the document (e.g. under the `<head>` element)?

Comment: Hi, when I tried to remove all the <script> element and left only the the <link> element, it still print out the code literally as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't why this behaviour, but I found an alternate solution

```
<link <%="href='../../css/style01.css?" + CssVersion + "'"%> rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, yeah this does work. I am still wondering why it does not want to interpret that CssVersion in <link> element but it can interpret if put in <script> element.

Answer (score 2):

Tim B James has the solution; you need to set a control to `runat='server'` before you can use those replacement tags (<%= %>).

Another solution, not recommended for your situation, is to register a javascript variable from the server:

Client Side:

```
<link href="../../css/style01.css?" +jvCSSVersion+ """ 
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Server Side:

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(getType(Page), "scrJV", 
    "var jvCSSVersion = '" + CssVersion + "';", true);
```